# Hyperlink a newly added cell value from a closed workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I can't seem to relate the discussion of this topic on this forum.
I have code here that uses `hyperlink` function but doesn't work.

I have a workbook opened at runtime `docname` that serves as a database.
And `wbSource` as current open workbook.
`wbSource` will send a cell value to `docname` and has to be converted into `hyperlink`.
`path` is the directory
`Dest` destination folder inside `path`
`wb.Cells(BB + 2, 2)` is the receiver. The file the hyperlink has to open is created almost the same time the link was created ( the line with the `saveas` command).

```
Set wb = Workbooks(DocName).Sheets("Sheet1")
Set wbs = Workbooks(wbSource).Sheets("MACRO")

Dim BB As Integer
wb.Cells(1, 1) = "=counta(B:B)"
BB = wb.Cells(1, 1)

wbNew = InputBox("Enter the 'Mold Number' or 'Part Name' here", "FileName")
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=Path & "\" & DesT & "\" & "RFQ Details_" & wbNew 
Open wbNew For Output As #1
Close #1

wb.Cells(BB + 2, 2) = Hyperlink(Path & "\" & DesT & "\" & "RFQ Details_" & wbNew) 'THIS PART DOES NOT WORK!
```

Everything is working pretty fine except the last line.
I feel somethings really missing on that last part.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Based on how you're using `DesT` in the `SaveAs` line, it looks like you're missing a path separator.

Comment: The `SaveAs` line works. The `hyperlink` does not.

Comment: i added path sepatator and still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tip**: Whenever you are in doubt, if MS Excel lets you, record a macro and simply edit it.

I am assuming that you have valid values for `BB`, `Path`, `Dest` and `DocName`

Is this what you are trying?

```
Dim completePath As String

completePath = Path & "\" & DesT & "\" & "RFQ Details_" & wbNew

Set ws = Workbooks(DocName).Sheets("Sheet1")
Set rng = ws.Cells(BB + 2, 2)

rng.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws.Range(rng.Address), _
                   Address:=completePath, _
                   TextToDisplay:=completePath
```

Tested it with the below sample values and it works :)

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim BB As Long: BB = 1
    Dim rng As Range

    Dim Path As String, DesT As String, wbNew As String
    Dim completePath As String

    '~~> Sample Values
    Path = "C:\Users\routs\Desktop"
    DesT = "test"
    wbNew = "Sample.xlsx"
    DocName = ThisWorkbook.Name

    Set wb = Workbooks(DocName)
    Set ws = Workbooks(DocName).Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set rng = ws.Cells(BB + 2, 2)

    completePath = Path & "\" & DesT & "\" & "RFQ Details_" & wbNew

    rng.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws.Range(rng.Address), _
                       Address:=completePath, _
                       TextToDisplay:=completePath
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the advise `@Siddharth Rout`. I will try your suggested code. i'll update you.

Comment: Yes dude this works, but the file in `wbNew` is defined at design time. I think you missed these lines from my original post: `wbNew = InputBox("Enter the 'Mold Number' or 'Part Name' here", "FileName")` and this one `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=Path & "\" & DesT & "\" & "RFQ Details_" & wbNew` The file to be open by the link is yet to be created the same time as the link. The file to be open is created at runtime.

Comment: I used `wbNew = "Sample.xlsx"` as a sample. Simply change that to suit your needs ;)

Comment: Anyway thanks for the time and help. You're quite a genius `@Siddharth Rout`

Comment: lol.. No I am not. I am still learning Excel... BTW did you manage to make it work?

Comment: Honestly, not yet. Still trying to figure out how to assign a file at `wbNew` at runtime. The file to be open is supposed to be this line `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=Path & "\" & DesT & "\" & "RFQ Details_" & wbNew`. where `wbNew` is input on the inputbox at runtime.

Comment: I am assuming that the user is supposed to enter something like "SomePartNumber.Xlsx". If yes then the next line will automatically pick it up. BTW, you may have to do proper error checking so that you get valid filename

Comment: Thanks for that dude. I'm gonna make it, im sure of it LOL;D

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why that did not work, but mine works, could you try this:

```
worksheets("Sheet1").hyperlinks.add _
    anchor:=range("A1"), _
    address:="https://9gag.com", _
    texttodisplay :="9Gag"
```

Edited Code:

```
wb.Hyperlinks.Add _ 
    anchor:=Cells(BB + 2, 2), _  
    Address:=(Path & "\" & DesT & "\" & "RFQ Details_" & wbNew), _  
    TextToDisplay:=Cells(BB + 2, 2)
```